# Merging csvs from multiple zip files python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I have a folder with many zip files. Each zip file is for a month of a year. Each zip file contains multiple csvs for each day of the month. The headers of all the csvs across all the zip files are the same.

I want to write a python script that uses pandas to merge all the csvs from all the zip files in my folder into one giant csv file.

zipfile name convention = yyyymmdddamasp_csv.zip

indivdual csv file naming convention= yyyymmdddamasp.csv

I'm a complete beginner to python**. I'm trying this potential solution but I'm not sure about it.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

# Path to the folder containing the zip files
folder_path = "path_to_folder_containing_zip_files"

# Initialize an empty list to store DataFrame for each CSV
dfs = []

# Iterate through each zip file in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
if file_name.endswith('.zip'):
# Open the zip file
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), 'r') as zip_ref:
# Iterate through each CSV file in the zip file
for csv_file_name in zip_ref.namelist():
if csv_file_name.endswith('.csv'):
# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
with zip_ref.open(csv_file_name) as csv_file:
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
# Append the DataFrame to the list
dfs.append(df)

# Concatenate all DataFrames in the list into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Save the combined DataFrame to a CSV file
combined_df.to_csv('combined_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: The indentation of the code is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Python requires consistent indenting for the *with*, *if*, and *for* statements in your code.

I copy-pasted your code, tried to run it, and got this error:

```
  File "/Users/zyoung/develop/StackOverflow/main.py", line 14
    if file_name.endswith(".zip"):
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 13
```

Reading that error, Python encountered an error at line 14, because the line above it, 13, was a for-statement.

To fix that, go to line 14 and indent all the lines that belong under the for-statement on line 13.  In a modern code editor, you can select the appropriate lines and use the `TAB` key to indent the selected lines at once:

```py
...
dfs = []

# Iterate through each zip file in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file_name.endswith(".zip"):
    # Open the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), "r") as zip_ref:
    # Iterate through each CSV file in the zip file
    for csv_file_name in zip_ref.namelist():
    if csv_file_name.endswith(".csv"):
    # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    with zip_ref.open(csv_file_name) as csv_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    # Append the DataFrame to the list
    dfs.append(df)

...
```

You'll need to repeat that for all the ifs, withs, and fors.

I understand you're new to Python.  Where did you get this code?  All the comments give me the impression it was created by a generative AI?  If so, that code was very like properly indented; try to go back and copy-paste again with the intent of making sure the indentation looks the same when you're done.